# 'readPulsioximeter' was not declared in this scope

Tags: arduino-uno

I am new to Arduino. I am trying to use Pulsioximeter sensor with e-health Platform (http://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/ehealth-biometric-sensor-platform-arduino-raspberry-pi-medical) on Arduino Uno. *Line number 13 is working fine in the example code given in the library and works just fine.* But when I try to upload my custom code (setup function definition is given below), **I get an error stating 'readPulsioximeter' not defined in this scope**. The error doesn't seem obvious to me. Please guide.

Here is the custom code upto setup() function:

```
#include < eHealth.h >
#include < PinChangeInt.h >
bool configuration = false;
//bool in_it=true;
byte val; // variable to receive data from the serial port
int ledpin = 13; // LED connected to pin 48 (on-board LED)
int A=1;
void setup() {
           pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT); 
           Serial.begin(115200);
           eHealth.initPulsioximeter();
           //Attach the interruptions for using the pulsioximeter.
           PCintPort::attachInterrupt(6, readPulsioximeter, RISING);
           delay(500);
}
```

**EDIT1:** 
readPulsioximeter is declared in eHealth.h library which has been included in program. The function has been defined as below in eHealth.cpp file:

```
    //!******************************************************************************
    //!     Name:   readPulsioximeter()                                             *
    //!     Description: It reads a value from pulsioximeter sensor.                *
    //!     Param : void                                                            *
    //!     Returns: void                                                           *
    //!     Example: readPulsioximeter();                                           *
    //!******************************************************************************
    void eHealthClass::readPulsioximeter(void)
    {
        uint8_t digito[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
        uint8_t A = 0;
        uint8_t B = 0;
        uint8_t C = 0;
        uint8_t D = 0;
        uint8_t E = 0;
        uint8_t F = 0;
        uint8_t G = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<6 ; i++) { // read all the led's of the module
            A = !digitalRead(13);
            B = !digitalRead(12);
            C = !digitalRead(11);
            D = !digitalRead(10);
            E = !digitalRead(9);
            F = !digitalRead(8);
            G = !digitalRead(7);
            digito[i] = segToNumber(A, B, C ,D ,E, F,G);    
            delayMicroseconds(2800); //2800 microseconds
        }
            SPO2 = 10 * digito[5] + digito[4];
            BPM  = 100 * digito[2] + 10 * digito[1] + digito[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have no function called "readPulsioximeter" in your code. Either define it, pick a different function, or remove that line of code.

Comment: readPulsioximeter is declared in eHealth.h library which has been included in program. Please see <b>EDIT1</b> in the the question.

Comment: :) Thanks for your help. I re-defined the function in the program and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your missed naming the eHealth object, and that that statement should read:

`PCintPort::attachInterrupt(6, eHealth.readPulsioximeter, RISING);`

as you did with the initPulsioximeter call. (In otherwords, "which pulsioximeter?").

Comment: When I try specifying eHealth.readPulsioximeter, it is shown as unresolved overloaded function type. Problem is that the same line is working in another program but gives error in this program.

Comment: :) Thanks for your help. I re-defined the function in the program and it worked.